# Android - playing video from sd card

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to play a video from a sd card, but I got an annoying error:

```
com.example.aidan.playvideo E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
```

and it doesn't work, here is the main code:

```
public class Video extends ActionBarActivity {

     String SrcPath = "/sdcard/Video/sintel.mp4"; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath(SrcPath);

        videoView.start();


        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Some logs:

```
11-14 18:39:00.497  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
11-14 18:39:00.497  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
11-14 18:39:00.607  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource(/storage/sdcard0/Video/sintel.mp4)
11-14 18:39:00.707  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
11-14 18:39:00.717  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
11-14 18:39:00.717  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
11-14 18:39:00.717  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
11-14 18:39:00.737  10670-10681/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
11-14 18:39:00.737  10670-10681/com.example.aidan.playvideo E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
11-14 18:39:00.737  10670-10681/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
11-14 18:39:00.737  10670-10681/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
11-14 18:39:00.917  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
11-14 18:39:00.917  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-2147483648
11-14 18:39:04.807  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
11-14 18:39:04.827  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
11-14 18:39:04.827  10670-10670/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ disconnect
11-14 18:39:04.827  10670-10682/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ destructor
11-14 18:39:04.837  10670-10682/com.example.aidan.playvideo V/MediaPlayer﹕ disconnect
```

Comment: What line of code is producing that error? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: i dont know which line, but i think that something is messed up with setVideoPath

Comment: Videos with url path working perfectly, the problem is with files on sd card